# **Undefined reference** error while linking two libraries referring to one-another

Tags: c, makefile, compilation, linker

I am getting **undefined reference** error while trying to compile *main* that refers to two libraries. I have two files *lib1/func1.c* and *lib2/func2.c* in separate folders. Those files contain two functions `print1()` and `print2()`, function `print1()` is calling `print2()`.
I am compiling those separately into two libraries `libfunc1.a` and `libfunc2.a`.
But when I am trying to compile *main* which is calling `print1()`, I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sv/ztest2/lib1/libfunc1.a(func1.o): in function print1:
/home/sv/ztest2/lib1/func1.c:7: undefined reference to print2
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:21: DP] Error 1
```

Here is the code and Makefiles:

**Makefile**:

```
TARGET = DP
HOME = /home/slav/FORECAST/ztest2

INCDIRS = -I./ \
      -I$(HOME)/lib1 \
      -I$(HOME)/lib2

LIBDIRS = -L$(HOME)/lib1 \
      -L$(HOME)/lib2

SRCFILES = DP.c
OBJFILES = DP.o

CFLAGS = -g -O3 $(INCDIRS)

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJFILES)
    cc $(CFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJFILES) $(LIBDIRS) -lfunc2 -lfunc1

clean:
    -rm *.o $(TARGET)
```

**DP.c**:

```
#include "func1.h"
int main()
{
    print1();
    return 0;
}
```

**func1.h**:

```
void print1();
```

**func1.c**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void print1()
{
    printf("print1 is called!\n");
    print2();
}
```

**func2.h**:

```
extern void print2();
```

**func2.c**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void print2()
{
    printf("print2 is called!\n");
}
```

Comment: Try linking with one of the libraries twice: `cc $(CFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJFILES) $(LIBDIRS) -lfunc2 -lfunc1 -lfunc2`

Comment: You need `#include "func2.h"` from DP.C.

Comment: @PaulSanders Thanks Paul, it looks like liking second libruary twice works!

Comment: @Slav Yep, it's an age-old trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Libraries must be listed in the order their symbols are needed.

The command `cc $(CFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJFILES) $(LIBDIRS) -lfunc2 -lfunc1` tells the linker to first use the `func2` library to resolve any pending references in the executable it is building and then to use the `func1` library.

Since the linker processes `func2` first, and, at the time it does so, there is no pending reference to `print2`, the linker does not include the module with `print2` in the executable.

Later, when the linker is processing `func1`, it includes the module with `print1` in the executable because `main` uses it. That module `print1` uses `print2`, so including that module adds a new reference to `print2`. Then, when the linker is done processing `func1`, it has an unresolved reference. The linker does not go back to `func2` to check it again.

Since the `func1` library depends on `func2`, change the link command to `cc $(CFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJFILES) $(LIBDIRS) -lfunc1 -lfunc2`.

(If the `func2` library also depends on `func1`, that is a bad design and should be reconsidered. If it is not changed, asking the linker to reconsider the libraries multiple times, as with `-lfunc1 -lfunc2 -lfunc1`, might fix the immediate problem, but others can arise.)